# Can Apache XMLBeans read and inject a partial XML document (fragment) into an XML document?

Tags: java, xml, xmlbeans

Suppose that I have something like this:

```
FooDocument fooDoc = FooDocument.Factory.newInstance();
fooDoc.addNewBar();
```

If I produced a string to represent `fooDoc`, it would look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Foo>
    <Bar/>
</Foo>
```

Now, suppose that I had a file that contained only this:

```
<Bar/>
```

And instead of adding `Bar` as a child of `Foo` programmatically, I wanted to read the file and add the contents of the file to the `fooDoc`, something like this:

```
FooDocument fooDoc = FooDocument.Factory.newInstance();
Bar bar = Bar.Factory.parse("file-containing-bar");
fooDoc.add(bar);
```

Is this possible to do with XML Beans? Obviously, the file containing only the `Bar` node is not an XML file.

Comment: Hm, why is the file containing only the Bar not node an XML file? The XML preamble is not mandatory. As long as the markup in the file contains a single root node and is also otherwise well-formed XML… why shouldn't it be possible to load it separately?

Comment: The `Bar` node is not a root node in the `Foo` schema, `Foo` is the root node.

Comment: The file containing the Bar node is an XML file, it just does not adhere to the schema. Have you looked at XmlCursor to do this? http://xmlbeans.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/reference/org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlCursor.html#copyXml(org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlCursor)

Comment: Why insist on XMLBeans? Why not just trivial string manipulation? Parse the result is you need a `Document` result.

Answer (score 0):

Unfornutaly, it is not possible with "ordinary" file. First of all, the file witch contains `<Bar/>` must be an XML file so that the incoming XML element could bind to XMLBeans type, and your file is not. In this reference you can read about it more: [XMLBeans](http://xmlbeans.apache.org/documentation/tutorial_getstarted.html)

If there is a possibity to convert you "ordinary" Bar file into an XML-file and have Foo as a root element in foo.xml and Bar as a root in bar.xml, then there exists a possible workaround such as this:

1) create 2 XML files
foo.xml - Foo element is root

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Foo>
    <Bar/>
</Foo>
```

and 
bar.xml - bar element is root

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Bar/>
```

2) Create 2 "Document" interface

```
FooDocument fooDocument = FooDocument.Factory.parse("foo.xml");
BarDocument barDocument = BarDocument.Factory.parse("bar.xml");
```

3) Create Bar instance

```
Bar barToCreate = fooDocument.getFoo().addNewBar();
```

4) do sth with the barToExploit (represent root element Bar from bar.xml)

```
Bar barToExploit = barDocument.getBar();
```

Then it is entirely up to you what you want to do with this barToExploit instance. Suppose, it has a child element  which stores a string, that you can do for example this:

```
barToCreate.setValue(barToExploit.getValue());
```

Answer (score -1):

you should be able to read the xml file into a array of strings, and then inject the contents where needed. you can use

```
    if(fileStringArray.contains("<foo> ++ seperator + </foo>"){//inject text}
```

to check for the content container in which you can place it, and then inject it there. then you can save the file as a xml file like so:

```
     while(fooDoc != null){
    fooDoc.write(YourString);
    fooDoc.write(Runtime().getRuntime().getProporty("line.seperator");
    }
```

or something like that.

hope this works! good luck.

Comment: Does this solution use XML Beans? The question is specifically about Apache XML Beans.

Comment: no, this is just a solution. It does not use Apache XML Beans, but will inject a string into a file. (I personally think it will work)